# When dynamically loading a windows dll how can I tell the name of a missing dependent module

Tags: windows, dll

I sometimes have a problem where dynamic libraries fail to load at customer sites.  This is usually because their system is configured wrong.
I need to be able to get the name of the dependent module that is missing so I can log it, and make fixing their systems much easier.
How can I accomplish this?
Note that I need an answer I can put in my code, this means I cannot use Dependency Checker, or Process Monitor, or any other tool to work out the problem.
I really do need a way to do it programatically.
The fact that Dependency Checker can do it means there is a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

begin from win7 `ntdll.dll` export next api:

```
struct FAILUREDATA 
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    WCHAR DllName[0x20];
    WCHAR FunctionName[0x20];
};

extern "C" NTSYSCALLAPI FAILUREDATA* NTAPI LdrGetFailureData();
```

`ntdll.dll` *Ldr-subsystem* log failure in 2 case - `GetProcAddress` fail (in this case `FunctionName` filled) or if *DLL* load fail. but with one exception - if top-level (i.e. *LibFileName* which you use in `LoadLibrary[Ex]` call) not found - failure not logged. but if dependent *DLL* not found (or fail initialize) - this error will be logged and name of dependent *DLL* recorded in `FAILUREDATA.DllName` (*if it longer than 31 symbol - it will be truncated*) - usual status in this case `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND` or `STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED`. also if top-dll found but fail initialize - this also will be logged. if some function will be not resolved during dll load - the `FunctionName` will be valid and usual status in this case - `STATUS_ENTRYPOINT_NOT_FOUND` or `STATUS_ORDINAL_NOT_FOUND`

unfortunately `LdrGetFailureData` not included in `ntdll[p].lib` - so need use `GetProcAddress` for get it. you can declare next global data:

```
static union {
    FAILUREDATA* (NTAPI *LdrGetFailureData)();
    PVOID pvLdrGetFailureData;
};
```

and on start call

```
pvLdrGetFailureData = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll"), "LdrGetFailureData");
```

then implement next function:

```
void OnLdrFail(PCWSTR TopDllName)
{
    if (LdrGetFailureData)
    {
        FAILUREDATA* pfd = LdrGetFailureData();

        if (NTSTATUS status = pfd->status)
        {
            DbgPrint("%x loaded DLL <%S> fail DLL <%S> %S\n", status, TopDllName, pfd->DllName, pfd->FunctionName);
        }
        else
        {
            // in case loaded(top) DLL not found
            DbgPrint("%x loaded DLL <%S>\n", GetLastError(), TopDllName);
        }
    }
}
```

*in place `DbgPrint` of course implement your real logging*

and you call `OnLdrFail` after `LoadLibraryW` fail. say like this

```
#define CLEAR_FAILURE_DATA() if (LdrGetFailureData) LdrGetFailureData()->status = 0

    CLEAR_FAILURE_DATA();
    HMODULE hmod = LoadLibraryW(lpLibFileName);
    if (!hmod)
    {
        OnLdrFail(lpLibFileName);
    }
```

because how i say Ldr not fill `FAILUREDATA` in case `lpLibFileName` not found - it not clear previous state of this structure - so need do this yourself (here can be previous error saved, unrelated to current call) (*however if dependent of `lpLibFileName` not found or any dll initialization fail - this will be logged*)

for example:

- `A.DLL` dependent from `B.DLL` and `B.DLL` not found will be next log

  `c0000135 loaded DLL <A.DLL> fail DLL <B.DLL>`
- if *DllMain* from `B.DLL` return FALSE

  `c0000142 loaded DLL <A.DLL> fail DLL <B.DLL>`
- if *DllMain* from `A.DLL` return FALSE

  `c0000142 loaded DLL <A.DLL> fail DLL <A.DLL>`
- if `A.DLL` import *SomeFunc* from `B.DLL` but `B.DLL` not export it

  `c0000139  loaded DLL <A.DLL> fail DLL <Unknown> SomeFunc`

Comment: Thanks, but it is returning status 0 for me.  I wonder if they changed how it worked in Windows Server 2016.  My test was loading a dll that needs other dlls that are not on the path.

Comment: @Solx - `pfd->status == 0` ? describe situation - what dll you loading, what is fail ?

Comment: It is a library of my own.  I verified that it can be loaded by using:  `hDll3 = LoadLibraryEx(libFile, 0, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES);`  Which returns a valid handle.  So my path is good.

Comment: I am going to try Process Monitor, to see if it is loading some other library before the call LdrGetFailureData();

Comment: I used Process Monitor, and no other dlls have been loaded successfully before the call LdrGetFailureData();   So the last error should have been from it failing to load my library.

Comment: One more bit of information it is a 32 bit dll I am trying to load and the test program I am using to see if this works is compiled 32 bit.

Comment: @Solx - now i check in win 10 - here already not more used `FAILUREDATA` - so what i describe work only on win 7 and 8.1. need search for another solution

Comment: The clients use Windows Server 2012.  Your solution worked when I ran it on Windows Server 2012!

Comment: @Solx - this is by fact windows 8.1 - here really worked, but for windows 10 need search for another.. i not check this at begin at this is broke

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138130/discussion-between-solx-and-rbmm).